# converting a PHP array to C#

Tags: c#, php

I'm needing help converting the php array in red below. I've been able to convert some of the arrays to dictionaries but not sure what the best solution
is since this is an array inside of an array .

```
$reg_rows=array();
$rc_count=0;
$reg_counter=0;
$hold_achtrndt="1970-01-01";
$hold_regpay_sort="0";
while ( ($row_rc=sqlsrv_fetch_assoc($result_rc)) ) 
    {
    if ( strtoupper(substr($row_rc['tb_value1'],4,1))=="Y" )
          $reg_counter=count($reg_rows);  //If the paymethod is set to require it's own deposit, increment
    elseif ( $row_rc['regpay_sort']!=$hold_regpay_sort ) 
    {
        $reg_counter=count($reg_rows);  //If the paymethod changes, increment so each different type is separated
        $hold_regpay_sort=$row_rc['regpay_sort'];
    }
    **$reg_rows[$reg_counter][$row_rc['rc_code']]=$row_rc;** //THIS IS THE ARRAY I NEED HELP WITH
    $rc_count++;
}
```

Maybe it would be easier if I showed you what I'm trying to get.Example below. where `0` and `1` would be the reg_counter and `5514`,`5115`,`5116` would be the `$row_rc['rc_code']` and the `array[78]` are the fields returned from SQL table.

```
$reg_rows[0][5515]{array[78]}
$reg_rows[1][5514]{array[78]}
$reg_rows[1][5516]{array[78]}
```

Comment: Not all arrays can be converted to dictionaries. Is the array in question a key-value pair?

Comment: Hello @trev52. Post what you have already done, and your doubt in the part that is not being able to translate. It's easier for us to help you.

Comment: PHP is too powerful to be converted into C#

Comment: You can't do it.

Comment: If you post at least the part of your C# code that corresponds to the `row_rc`, people will be able to suggest better solutions (e.g. using LINQ). In the meanwhile I posted a general approach involving a `Dictionary<TOuterKey, Dictionary<TInnerKey, TValue>>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi trev52 and welcome to Stackoverflow!

As you said, you have an associative array¹ inside the values of an array.

In C#, you would have a dictionary placed inside the values of an array, or inside the values of an outer dictionary. More precisely, if we knew the size of the outer array in advance, we could write

```
var size = 42; // let's assume we know this somehow
var outer = new Dictionary<InnerKey, InnerValue>[size];
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
  for (key in some_source) {
    var value = some_function(key);
    if (outer[i] == null) {
      outer[i] = new Dictionary<InnerKey, InnerValue>();
    }
    outer[i].Add(somekey, somevalue);
  }
}
```

However, in this case we don't know the size of the array in advance, and resizing the array on the fly in C# is going to be a pain, so we'll use a dictionary whose values are dictionaries themselves:

```
var outer = new Dictionary<Int, Dictionary<InnerKey, InnerValue>>;
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
  for (key in some_source) {
    var value = some_function(key);
    if (!outer.ContainsKey(i)) {
      outer.Add(i, new Dictionary<InnerKey, InnerValue>());
    }
    outer[i].Add(somekey, somevalue);
  }
}
```

Note that you can also create elements in dictionaries with `d[k] = v`. If the key already exists `d[k] = v` will overwrite its value, but `d.Add(k, v)` will raise an exception, therefore it is safer to use `Add` if you know the keys are supposed to be unique.

For clearer code, at the cost of some slightly more complex features, you could get rid of the manual instantiation of the inner dictionaries using a `DefaultDictionary`. You could also quite likely get rid of the loops by using LINQ. It looks a lot like SQL with some C# syntax, and is able to manipulate C# lists, dictionaries, arrays and so on. The SQL binding that you are using might even have a LINQ interface!

¹ An arrays which keys are not integers is usually called an associative array (it associates a value to a key).

Comment: Why do you jump from array of dictionaries to an Dictionary<int, Dictionary<K,V>> just because the array size is not known beforehand? Wouldn't be more straightforward and simpler to go from an array to a List<Dictionary<K,V>> if the number of dictionaries is not known beforehand?

Comment: @elgonzo good point, that would work too. Please don't hesitate to edit my post, my C# is a bit rusty — haven't used it in the past few years :) .